# inapp purchase for non-consumable products in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am working on inapp purchase.  do I implement  to restore transactions for non-consumable products  in my code ?

As   I read Store Kit provides built-in functionality to restore transactions for non-consumable products

Please let me know if any body knows about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a "Restore purchases" button to users in your app so they can restore already purchased non-consumable products. This is mandatory and without such a button, Apple rejects apps.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion